# String condition check

Tags: java, regex, performance, algorithm

I have string which always contain either x or y and i have to  validate based on below condition

- Condition 1 : If all character are same return true (Like : 'xxxxx')
- Condition 2 : If all are same except one character return true ( Like
  : 'xxxxy')
- Condition 3 : If all character are  same and other character is more 
  than one time retun false . (Like : 'xxxyy' // y exist 2 times)

How to check this  without writing complex for loop with condition .    Is there any solution using xor or will it be helpful if I store    string as boolen or number ( x=1 or true y=0 or false).

Comment: So is `yyyyx` true, and is `yyyxyyx` false? What is 'xyxyx` ?

Comment: Condition 3 doesnt make sense to me, could elaborate on that a bit better thanks

Comment: Yes @JonathanM In yyyyx  majority is y and one x is allowed but in yyyxyyx majority is y but x occurs more than once

Comment: In third condition which ever character is having majority in string apart from that one extra character is allowed , not more than once .@Saruman

Comment: If you want to count the `x`'s in the string, try `s.replaceAll("y","").length()`, if I understand the problem.  You should be able to figure out an answer based on this and the length of the original string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x*(yx*)?|y*(xy*)?` seems to be doing what you want. You can change first `*` to `+` if you don't want to accept empty strings.

In short:

- `*` is quantifier meaning that element before it can appear *zero or more times*
- `?` means that element before it is optional
- `|` is OR operator

so in `x*(yx*)`

- `x*` represents zero or more of `x` characters, which means it can represent empty string `""`, `x`, `xx`, `xxx`, and so on
- `yx*` can represent strings which are `y` with zero or more `x`es after it like `y`, `yx`, `yxx`

This regex is trying to check if string is either

- `xxxx` with optional `yxxx` part,
- `yyyy` with optional `xyyy` part.

Demo

```
String regex = "x*(yx*)?|y*(xy*)?";

System.out.println("xxx".matches(regex));
System.out.println("xxxy".matches(regex));
System.out.println("xxyx".matches(regex));
System.out.println("xxxyy".matches(regex));
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
false
```

---

> How to check this without writing complex for loop with condition

It depends on what you mean by *complex*. Loop such as this is quite simple IMO

```
public static boolean check(String text){
    long xCounter = 0;
    long yCounter = 0;
    for (char ch : text.toCharArray()){
        if (ch=='x') xCounter++;
        else if (ch=='y') yCounter++;
        else return false;//non x or y appeared
    }
    return xCounter < 2 || yCounter < 2;
}
```

Comment: But it may have 'Y' in between like xxyxx ? Then also it should return true

Comment: @Sumeet It does. Test it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to resort to regexes here, I should think; the regex compilation is likely to take more runtime than simply walking through the string and checking the characters. (The post is tagged "performance, after all)

This is somewhat more difficult to write down in a pretty manner than I first expected, but it's not terrible, and it should be fairly fast:

```
public static boolean foo(String str) {
  // if the string only has three characters, both can't be in it twice.
  if(str.length() < 4) {
    return true;
  }

  // To start with, assume that the first character is the main
  // character (the one that appears more often). Search for the
  // other one.
  char needle = str.charAt(0) == 'x' ? 'y' : 'x';
  int first = str.indexOf(needle, 1);

  if(first == -1) {
    // Didn't find the other character at all.
    return true;
  }

  if(first ==  1) {
    // The first two characters are different from each other.
    // What we first thought was the main character might be
    // the lesser after all.
    needle = str.charAt(2) == 'x' ? 'y' : 'x';

    // skip unnecessary check.
    first = 2;
  }

  return str.indexOf(needle, first + 1) == -1;
}
```

Comment: Won't work for `"yxxxx"`, which I think satisfies condition 2.  Perhaps with one more test you could catch this case.

Comment: Ah, true. Will fix. EDIT: Hm. It is getting a bit ugly, though probably still faster than the regex. Let me think a minute.

Comment: Will it work for xxyxx , In this case also it should return true as y occurred once only

Comment: Yes, it will. But there has to be a prettier way to write down this algorithm.

Comment: Well, this appears to be about as pretty as it gets. Should be quick, though.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I think this will work for you:

```
if (str.length() < 4)
    return true;
String reduction = str.replaceAll("y","");
if (reduction.length() < 2 || (str.length() - reduction.length()) < 2)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```